# Wordpress add Google tag manager script to header.php

Tags: wordpress, google-tag-manager

The Google tag manager requires me to put one script inside the "head" tag and one at the beginning of the "body" tag.

I want to know what would be considered "best practise" to achieve this.
Are there any other ways than to create a child theme and place the Script in the header.php file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use "Insert Headers and Footers by WPBeginner" plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin for GTM and other scripts:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duracelltomi-google-tag-manager/